# Mathematica - How do I show of intersections of two functions on plot?

Tags: function, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have defined the two functions:

`f[x_] := 40*1.04^x`

`g[x_] := 150*0.9^x`

And then I'm plotting them:

`Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 20}]`

But how do I show the intersection(s) of such two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 40*1.04^x
g[x_] := 150*0.9^x

sol = Quiet[Solve[f[x] == g[x], x]];
xpts = x /. sol;
ypts = f /@ xpts;

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 20},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Orange,
   Map[Point, Transpose[{xpts, ypts}]]}]
```

Comment: I really need to learn how to use map and replace in Wolfram... but thanks!